# Getting error while using LookAtMe feature in Android-

Tags: android

I am trying to use the LookAtMe feature, when running from MainActivity, it runs absolutely fime but while trying to run on a button click from a different activity , I getting below error. tried all possible options but not able to resolve it, any help is highly appreciated-

I am getting this error on line : `lookAtMe.init(com.example.videoexample.VVedio.this);`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.videoexample, PID: 12517
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbgl;
        at com.pd.lookatme.LookAtMe.createCameraSource(LookAtMe.java:222)
        at com.pd.lookatme.LookAtMe.init(LookAtMe.java:35)
        at com.example.videoexample.VVedio$1.onClick(VVedio.java:40)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6642)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6619)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26189)
```

Comment: Hi @Bibhu Sahoo, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What does your code tied to the `lookAtMe` variable look like? We're going to need more than you've already provided to have a good chance at helping. :-)

Comment: Thanks for responding .. appreciate... I am following line by line as per the link (https://githubhelp.com/Pradyuman7/LookAtMe)  from Github, the only new thing I am trying is run it from a different activity than MainActivity.  the flow is .. ManinActvity - couple of button to play around, in one of the button , i am trying to access the vedio using LookAtMe and I am not able to get that, it is failing at lookAtMe.init(com.example.videoExample.VVedio.this);    ..ending with those errors